# How to change the width (or the size) of a visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, size

I have a visualforce page, in which I have a button that open a new visualforce page.

The problem I have is that the new page is too small (`like a popup`), and I want to set the width of my new page. It is possible ? And how can I do that ?

Thanks :)

Code

```
<apex:commandButton value="Enregistrer" action="{!enregistrer}" 
   onclick="enregistrerBlocks()" oncomplete="CloseAndRefresh()" rerender="msg"/>
```

Comment: Can you please post some code snippet, what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think I post my question too fast because I just find how to do that ^^
In salesforce, in the parameters of my button (custom button or link) I choose the button that open my new page and click the Window Open Properties button and here we can change the size (height and width, and some other things) of the displayed page !

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using `window.open`, set the **width and height**

```
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", "_blank", "width=400, height=400");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.w3schools.com/', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250'); return false;">
   Click here to open new window
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Use this code implement here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open

```
<apex:commandButton value="Click Me" action = "{!method2}" 
 oncomplete="window.open('http://www.w3schools.com', '_blank', 'width=400, height=400');"/>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ratan, but my page is open via an appex:commandButton and not a link....

Comment: @dou Can you please add your commandButton code. If you are using commandButton then you are using oncomplete for open new window ? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: <apex:commandButton value="Enregistrer" action="{!enregistrer}" onclick="enregistrerBlocks()" oncomplete="CloseAndRefresh()" rerender="msg"/>  the oncomplete parameter is already used by calling an othe javascript function, that close my page and refresh the other page

Comment: @dou one more request where you are using window.open for opening new VF page. is in this method `CloseAndRefresh` if yes pls add this function code as well.  Just provide me the code where you are opening new VF page

Comment: I just tried with your method, and changing my oncomplete parameter and I can change th esize of the window ! Thank you :) But As I said in my answer I found an other way to change th e size of the window, but by changing some parameters in salesforce. It's cool that there is two differnets ways to do that, I'll try to remember your answer ''cause it coulb be very usefull, thank you ;)